# Need help understanding something like while ((status = SOME_STATUS == FunctionName(params)))

Tags: c

I'm seeing in one of the files I've inherited the following line

```
while ((status = SOME_STATUS == FunctionName(params)))
```

Obviously names have been changed, but you get the idea.  Can someone explain to me how the compiler sets the values and in what order...

I'm thinking that status get set to SOME_STATUS and then is set the result of the function?

I've never seen this in all my years developing.  Why in the world would someone do this?  It's completely nuts... or maybe I am!

Thanks.
-stv

Comment: I wouldn't trust evaluation order. The guy who wrote this is a playful one... It would be better to understand what the code should do, and then rewrite or put parentheses at the proper locations so it doesn't trip other people (or compilers :))

Comment: `==` has higher precedence, so this assigns a 1 or 0 to status.

Comment: I equally don't trust the OP. Would like to see the original line...

Comment: Thanks for the replies... And I'm much more like you Jean-François Fabre, I don't trust anything.  I'm just trying to figure out the logic bug that was introduced.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I love code like this since once you've memorised your operator precedence table, it's extremely clear.

= has lower precedence than ==, that's all.

If you insert the superfluous parentheses it's obvious that status is 1 or 0 acccording to the test of relational equality.

The double opening parentheses probably suppress a compiler warning.

Comment: I can't stand code that is written like this.  Maybe if there were some sort of speed vs. size advantage I get it, it just takes WAY too much brain power if you have to come in and read this code and debug it.  Because the bug was, the original author's logic was wrong.... anyway.. thanks for the reply...

Answer (score 2):

The expression `SOME_STATUS==Func(Params)` is a boolean expression resolving to `true` or `false`, thus `while( status = <boolean expression>)` means:

1. Assign variable `status` with `true` (`SOME_STATUS == Func(Params)`) or `false` (`SOME_STATUS != Func(Params)`)
2. Continue with loop untill `status` is `false` (i.e. -
   `SOME_STATUS != Func(Params)`)

I must admit that I prefer a more readable code:

```
  ...
  if( STATUS_OK != Func( Params))
    bContinue = false; // or break;

} while( bContinue);
```